# Refreshing Ember Objects Based on Geolocation API

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, geolocation, handlebars.js

I'm querying a JSON API that depends on the user's latitude and longitude, obtained via the Geolocation API. With the code below, my template shows "No categories found" even though in the console I can see the response and the Category objects being created correctly. Is there a way I can refresh my template so that the `each` statement will actually print out my category names? I'm thinking that the template is rendering before the browser actually get's the coordinates, and is not updating after the Category objects are created.

#### app.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Category = Ember.Object.extend();

App.Category.reopenClass({
    list: function(lat, lon) {
        return $.getJSON("/api_url?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon).then(function(response) {

            var categories = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                categories.push(App.Category.create({ name: response[i]}));
            }

            // after the lat and lon load, this get's logged correctly
            console.log(categories);

            return categories;
        });
    }
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCategories);

        function getCategories(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lon = position.coords.longitude;
            return App.Category.list(lat, lon);
        }
    }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['name']
});
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ember App</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
        <h1>Ember App</h1>
        <div id="content">
            {{outlet}}
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
        <ul>
            {{#each}}
                <li>{{name}}</li>
            {{else}}
                <li>No categories found</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>  
    </script>

    <script src="/js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/libs/ember-1.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

model hook returns nothing. Because you return in callback function which executed later

I am not 100% sure but try this

```
return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lon = position.coords.longitude;
  return App.Category.list(lat, lon);
});
```

if does not help I suggest you to check out Ember.RSVP you need promise function.